# Chicken out followed by an infinitive

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

Is it possible to use "infinitive" after chicken out?

She chickened out to go there by herself.

Answer (score 17):

That's not how we'd phrase it, no.

Most people would say:

> She chickened out **of** going there by herself.

Comment: Alternate suggestion: "She chickened out and didn't go there by herself."

Comment: another alt: "[When it came to] going there by herself, she chickened out" [] portion is very malleable.